# Display console on usb screen without X server

Tags: linux, raspbian, touch-screen, x

I'm running a custom version of raspbian on my raspberry pi, it has no X server running only in text mode with only basic services installed. i got a usb monitor that i want to plug in and use to show the console, i plugged it in it's detected and showing a green screen but i'm not sure what i can do to achieve my goal if that's even possible. Any of you can give some pointers ?

dmesg log:

```
[ 1606.712232] udlfb: DisplayLink LILLIPUT USB Monitor - serial #70873920033
[ 1606.724237] udlfb: vid_17e9&pid_02a9&rev_0130 driver's dlfb_data struct at b8d6d800
[ 1606.741459] udlfb: console enable=1
[ 1606.749754] udlfb: fb_defio enable=1
[ 1606.757827] udlfb: shadow enable=1
[ 1606.766183] udlfb: vendor descriptor length:17 data:17 5f 01 00 15 05 00 01 03 00 04
[ 1606.782954] udlfb: DL chip limited to 1500000 pixel modes
[ 1606.794348] udlfb: allocated 4 65024 byte urbs
[ 1606.885797] udlfb: 800x480 @ 59 Hz valid mode
[ 1606.894588] udlfb: Reallocating framebuffer. Addresses will change!
[ 1606.906132] udlfb: 800x480 @ 59 Hz valid mode
[ 1606.914741] udlfb: set_par mode 800x480
[ 1606.927843] udlfb: DisplayLink USB device /dev/fb1 attached. 800x480 resolution. Using 1504K framebuffer memory
```

Comment: It's funny that the answers in the "duplicate" don't actually mention `con2fbmap`, which was important for the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dev/fb1` means it gives you a [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) device ([here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt) is the kernel API documentation). So you can use any software that can use such a framebuffer device (there's a number of them, e.g. picture viewers, or terminals).

Linux consoles use framebuffer devices via [fbcon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt), and there's a parameter `map` to specify which consoles work on which framebuffer devices.

I haven't tried this myself (because I only have a single framebuffer device), but I'd assume by booting with this argument, one should be able to put a number of Linux consoles on your USB monitor. Alternatively, use `con2fbmap` to change the assignment after boot.

Unless of course you find it easier to use applications directly on the framebuffer, like starting a framebuffer terminal emulator.

Comment: didn't know it was this easy, after installing `apt-get install fbset` and running `con2fbmap 1 1` everything working now. appreciate the help